# How do I detect if an external hard drive is connected

Tags: winapi, nim-lang

I am trying to translate some code I use to run a backup to Nim (as part of learning the language).  How do I detect if one of my external hard drives is connected (by name?) and then  which drive letter my Windows 10 PC has assigned to it?

Answer (score 1):

With Window message: [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/wm-devicechange) and winapi [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerdevicenotificationa)